# Use property as form validator in Angular2 (data-driven)

Tags: forms, angular, data-driven

I'm having a hard time trying to set a max value using the data driven approach in Angular2.
I want to set the max value of the input to a property called userLimit, which I get from firebase. This is my code:

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit  } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormControl } from "@angular/forms";
import { FiredbService } from '../services/firedb.service';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-dashboard',
  styleUrls: ['./recibirpago.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: './recibirpago.component.html'
})
export class RecibirpagoComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  myForm2: FormGroup;
  uid: string;
  userLimit: any;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
              private dbfr: FiredbService,
              private db: AngularFireDatabase,
              private authService: AuthService) {

     this.myForm2 = this.fb.group({
      email: ['', Validators.email],
      clpmount: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.max(this.userLimit)]]
      });

   }

ngOnInit() {
    this.uid = this.authService.getUserUid();
} 

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.dbfr.getUserLimit(this.uid).subscribe(snapshot => {          
    this.userLimit = snapshot.val().accountLimit;
    console.log(this.userLimit);
    })
}
```

If I write, for example, Validators.max(5000) it works, but if I try to get the data from Firebase it doesn't work.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: try getting the value of userLimit before you create the form by formbuilder in your constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the constructor is executing *before* the ngAfterViewInit so you don't have the value of the userLimit at that point.

Instead use the `setVAlidators` method within the subscribe where you get the data.

Something like this:

**constructor**

```
 this.myForm2 = this.fb.group({
  email: ['', Validators.email],
  clpmount: ['', Validators.required]  // <-- not here
  });
```

**ngAfterViewInit**

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.dbfr.getUserLimit(this.uid).subscribe(snapshot => {          
    this.userLimit = snapshot.val().accountLimit;
    console.log(this.userLimit);
    const clpControl = this.myForm2.get(`clpmount');
    clpControl.setValidators(Validators.max(this.userLimit)); // <-- HERE
    clpControl.updateValueAndValidity();
    })
}
```

NOTE: Syntax was not checked.